# How can i call method from usercontrol from another usercontrol using c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two usercontrols: `UserControl1` and `UserControl2`.
`UserControl1` have a `Update()` method.

I need call `UserControl2`  in the call  `UserControl1` `Update()` method.How can it?

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code example perhaps? More context would be helpful to see your possible method signature constraints e.g..

Comment: more context please, there are to many solutions to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `System.Action` like so even making the parameter of `UserControleOne` optional.

```
    class UserControlOne
    {
        public void Update(Action updateAction = null)
        {
            updateAction?.Invoke(); # you could also write updateAction();
        }
    }

    class UserControlTwo
    {
        public void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Updated");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // calling exmaple 1
            UserControlOne uc = new UserControlOne();
            UserControlTwo uc2 = new UserControlTwo();
            uc.Update(uc2.Update);

            // calling example 2
            UserControlOne anotherUserControl = new UserControlOne();
            anotherUserControl.Update();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is 'Invoke()'

Comment: @Jana `updateAction?.Invoke();` is just a fancy way of calling the method that was passed as a parameter `Action updateAction` so it executes at that moment. I used `Invoke()` in order to be able to do the null-check with the [Safe Navigation Operator `?`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator). I also added a comment to my code showing a different way of achieving the same but **without** the null-check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access method using object of Usercontrol, you have to register it like this

```
UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
uc1.Update();
```

Comment: public void updaeData()
        {
            texOne.Text= "Saved!";
        }

Comment: this is small method. not show Error. but not working frand

Comment: there should be something wrong, i need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the instance of the first User Control into the second:

```
UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
UserControl2 uc2 = new UserControl2(uc1);
```

....
    // Set the uc1 object to a private member variable in uc2 in the constructor, then..

```
//With the object of uc1 in uc2, update it
uc1.Update();
```

Comment: ex plane please sir